# Adding multiple Marker animation by route id in OpenLayers by angular

Tags: openlayers, angular

I want to show more than route in map like in this example
http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_multipleMarkerAnimation.html
but generate it by id and with different color from json
I follow this link
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/feature-move-animation.html

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can simply wrap the fetch block in a function, add some more buttons to the HTML, then you can call the function for each of your jsons, passing a different style and control button for each one.

```
function addRoute(json, styles, startButton) {
  fetch(json).then(function (response) {

    // all other code in fetch block unchanged
    // except const styles = ...;
    // and const startButton = ...;
    // blocks removed

  });
}
```